# ¿Cómo obtener las coordenadas de la API de Google Maps cuando el usuario arrastre el Marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api

En mi pagina web quiero implementar el api de google maps, y que el usuario arrastre el marcador(Marker) en la ubicacion donde vive y luego mostrar la latitud y longitud en un input para posterior guardarlo en una base de datos.

Aquí como lo hice pero no me funciona:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<input type="text" id="coords" />
<script>


var marker;
var coords = {};

initMap = function ()
{

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position){
            coords =  {
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
              lat: position.coords.latitude
            };
            setMapa(coords);


          },function(error){console.log(error);});

}



function setMapa (coords)
{

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      {
        zoom: 13,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),

      });

      marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);

      marker.addListener( 'dragend', function (event)
      {
        document.getElementById("coords").value = this.getPosition().lat()+","+ this.getPosition().lng();
      });
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD1tGk92O2ExGvtxy6rIZkwC7xtuyzHymg&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: muy interesante. y se podría hacer una consulta a la api de maps para que me devuelva todas las coordenadas de X stablecimientos? por ejemplo quiero saber las coordenadas de todas las gasolineras Repsol de Galicia. gracias

Answer (score 2):

La posición la obtienes mediante el evento de la siguente manera

`event.latLng.lat();`
`event.latLng.lng();`

para asignar el evento debes usar `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {...`,  no directamente al marcador

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del evento, la variable `this` es el marker.

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     zoom: 3,
     center: {lat: -10, lng: -60}
   });
   
   var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:map.getCenter(), 
      map:map, 
      draggable:true
   });
   
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
      document.getElementById("coords").value = this.getPosition().toString();
   });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <input type="text" style="width:400px" id="coords" />
<div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="map-canvas" style="height:200px;"></div>
```

[Revisa el plunkr que te hice](https://plnkr.co/edit/aApoREJhdm5dNzFhBlDK?p=preview)